# VLOOKUP and populating a cell with text if highlighted a certain color

Tags: excel, vlookup, highlighting

Is there a way to populate a cell with text if a cell (or cells) from another sheet are highlighted a certain color?  For instance, if a cell from sheet 1 is highlighted orange, I need to populate a cell in sheet 2 with "Accepted".  If a cell from sheet 1 is highlighted green, I populate a cell in sheet 2 with "Rejected".  I have found a way to do the opposite (highlight a cell if a certain text appears) but there are people who don't want colors involved on this sheet, only text.

Comment: Can you use the same rules you would use for conditional formatting, except instead of conditional formatting just put a formula in the cells you want to populate that results in `IF(ruleforaccepted=TRUE,"Accepted",IF(ruleforrejected=TRUE,"Rejected",""))`?

Comment: Relying on if a cell is colored or not is generally bad practice, and would probably need VBA.

Comment: You will need VBA if you're trying to make it trigger by color.  If you change the trigger from coloring the cell to evaluating the cell next to it for say `O` for `Orange` or `G` for `Green`, this could be done with a normal excel formula.

Comment: Thank you all. I was just wondering if this was a quick VLookup with nested IF statement kind of formula that I was overthinking but the consensus seems to be that it would require heavy macro lifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer: No, there isn't.

Formulae do not look at the colour of a cell, they're solely concerned with its contents. Colours are provided for human use and making things look good, not for programmatic use.

### Long answer: Yes, but it's cumbersome and awkward to use.

You can do this with VBA. I used to have a macro that I would give people who wanted to do this, but before I ever gave them the macro I would give them my firm advice, four or five times, to do this ANY other way. Colour is unreliable and variable, and any change in practice is going to catch you out.  Instead of using colour, have values to put in the cells; it's much much **much MUCH *MUCH*** more reliable.